# vee-validate - How to add rules in external file

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I am not able to add rules in external files.

If I use the code below, I got this error **Uncaught ReferenceError: required is not defined**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend( 'required', required );

Vue.component( 'ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver );
Vue.component( 'ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider );
```

When I move the code into the component, the code starts working. What am I doing wrong?

```
import {  extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend( 'required', required );
```

Comment: What happens if you move your `Vue.component` lines before the `extend` line?

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

vee-validate rules are evaluated lazily so they can be extended at any time as long as the `ValidationProvider` didn't invoke it yet as a result of user interaction.

I think you just misplaced things when trying to tidy things up. You can have a `vee-validate.js` setup file to add all your rules in:

```js
// vee-validate.js
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend('required', required);

// other rules ....
```

In your `main.js` you could then import vee-validate components and register them, but don't forget to import the `vee-validate.js` setup file:

```js
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';
import './vee-validate';

Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver);
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
```

That should allow you to use `ValidationProvider` and `ValidationObserver` anywhere in your components with the rules defined in `vee-validate.js`